# What should be the filename for files with date name so it would order by desc

Tags: file, time

I'm creating an application which writes log files daily and i'd like to know **what should be the file name** for each day so if all files located in the same folder they would be ordered in a desc order (from the newest to the oldest)?

Comment: Why worry about file naming? Pretty much every shell in existence has the capability to sort by file metadata, which includes time-of-creation. e.g. `ls -t` or `dir /od`

Comment: most likely to make life easier since i don't know how many files are going to be created, i always want the last one to be on top of the list.

Comment: then the file sort option is most reliable, since you're not depending on the filenames for ordering.

Comment: can't i somehow create the files so i won't have to sort by any filter later on?

Comment: no, because filenames are not used for ordering by default within a filesystem. the standard view is to offer them up as they're found, not sorted by anything. `ls` by default sorts by name, but that's something ls does, not the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the following format: "yyyy-MM-dd_hh_mm_ss" and sort your files in your folder by name, descending.

Comment: ... and if there can be multiple instances of your app, append pid ( process id ) to log file name

Comment: This is not exactly right since yyyy-MM-dd... would cause that first file can be 2012-03-01 and second file would be 2012-04-01 in that case 04 should be first since april is most recent.

Comment: That's why I mentioned sorting the files in the folder by name descending.  I am assuming he has that functionality available to him in whatever method he's viewing his files.

Answer (score 0):

You may substract from a date in the future, from 2033 for example:

```
echo $((2000*1000*1000 - $(date +%s)))
669025348
```

The multiplication is far better readable than 2000000000. The current date in s is:

```
date +%s
1330974665
```

so this will be a stable method for about 20 years from now.

A better readable way would be, to negate every part of the numeric date:

```
echo > $(date +-%Y.-%m.-%d.-%H.-%M.-%S)

ls
-2012.-03.-05.-20.-46.-07  -2012.-03.-05.-20.-46.-16  -2012.-03.-05.-20.-46.-24
ls | sort -n 
-2012.-03.-05.-20.-46.-07
-2012.-03.-05.-20.-46.-16
-2012.-03.-05.-20.-46.-24
```

It looks curios, is not nice to handle, since you will have to use

```
rm -- *
```

to delete all these files, because

```
rm *
```

will lead to misinterpretation of the - sign. But you can detect the real date.

Comment: thank u for the answer BUT I dont really see how is the output related to dates.. maybe what i'm trying to achieve is not really possible?

Comment: To see from which date the file origins, you would need to do `ls -l`. How else do you think a backwards sorting should be possible with readable dates? Another idea would be to just put a "-" in front of every datepart. I put it into the answer.